# How to create a circular black gradient mask

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, gradient, mask

Last year I hired someone to do some work for our website but accidentally lost the PSD files since then. It's a fairly basic concept but I am fairly inexperienced with using masks.

How can I create the black circular gradient area as shown in this image below? I need to get as close as possible where it matches existing images on the site, why I am hoping its not too hard.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What tutorials have you looked at? Showing some effort will likely get you better answers

Comment: I tried making a circular selection similar in size to the one in that image. I then made a layer mask and applied a reverse radial gradient overlay with black -> transparent. It kind of worked but not close enough

Comment: Actually a reverse radial gradient overlay seems to be perfect, however I do need to reposition it. I tried doing it on a transparent layer but it didn't show up. Is there any way to do that so I can just lay it over the top of an image?

Comment: You can create a black filled layer of the image. Make a circle selection, feather it (select -> refine edge) and delete the selection. You can move the top black layer around. You can also make a circle selection, delete the selection. Then go to filter -> Gaussion Blur.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it a couple of ways

1) Make background layer black.

2) Paste graphic on a new layer

3) Create a layer mask for Layer 1 (second layer)

[image]

Your layers so far

[image]

4) Use a black & White gradient on the layer mask

[image]

result

[image]