# Gradient fade a PNG image using Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

I've searched high and low and finally hit upon alpha channels, but I don't know how to configure an alpha channel to suit my needs. **I'm trying take this image...**

[image: before]

**...And turn it into this.** As you can see the top portion is 100% opaque, and the bottom is 0%. So its a kind of "alpha mask". How can I do this with Photoshop or Gimp or whatever, and save it into a 32-bit PNG?

[image: result]

I'm not simply trying to "cover" or "mask" my image like [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46753/how-to-create-a-circular-black-gradient-mask). I'm trying an alpha mask which is a whole different ballgame.

Comment: @AndrewH - Its NOT a duplicate. That question simply covers the image with a transparent gradient. My question is how to generate a transparent image, an "alpha mask" if you will.

Comment: No Geotarget it indeed does exactly what you ask. It is a alpha mask. The demo image just has a black background so you think its a gradient with alpha. Please read again. If the last layer wouldnt be black it would do exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can use clipping masks to achieve this effect!!**

1. Create 2 layers in photoshop
2. In the 1st layer place your image content
3. Click the 2nd layer
4. Select White as the foreground & background color (by clicking the color swatches on the toolbar)
5. Click the gradient tool, and choose the "opaque to transparent" gradient (the 2nd gradient in the palette)

[image: step]

**6. Draw a gradient on the 2nd layer**

[image]

**7. Right-click the 1st layer and choose "Create Clipping Mask"**

[image]

**8. Done!**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually work with the example image in your original post. You should basically do the same thing, but with [Layer mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) instead of a [Clipping mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/revealing-layers-clipping-masks.html).

Comment: While I agree a layer mask would be better, why wouldn't a clipping mask work for the original image?